# Are there any plugins yet that support Facebook Like, Google +1 and allow Social Interaction tracking on Google Analytics

Tags: plugins, facebook, google-analytics

I know that Google +1 is quite new (at time of writing), but I wondered if there were any plugins that support these. By "Social Interaction tracking on Google Analytics" I mean - that use this code - http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSocial.html?utm_source=helpCenter&utm_medium=helpCenter&utm_campaign=social&utm_content=socialPluginTracking

The alternative is to find a plugin that supports the first two and add my own analytics, but I wondered if someone had done it already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I went with the plugin from addthis.com which can be customised to work with +1.

Answer (score 2):

This one is brand new: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/social-media-tracking/ and it sounds like it does what you want.

But be watching [Joost de Valk's GA plugin](http://yoast.com/wordpress/).  He mentioned just a few days ago in [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/google-analytics-social-tracking) that he's working on it right now.  He's a prominent plugin author in the community and does good work.

If you want to implement your own, you can probably look at the Social Media Tacking plugin to see how they do it, and then go from there.

Have fun!

Comment: I found that first one, but because it's new I'm not sure if the developers will keep it up to date. I'll watch that other one, thanks.